# How to expand textarea upwards and its parent divs along with it

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm creating a chat application(React). I'm having this textbox which I need to expand vertically upwards as user types. I tried doing it with position absolute but it takes it out of the normal flow. And this does not allow the parent div to move upwards. Is there a way that this can be done? If anyone could point me in the right direction that would be great. Thanks.

Here is the codepen link.

https://codepen.io/ghewadesumit/pen/zYzRjyY

```
<div class='chat-inputbox-container'>
  <div class='chat-inputbox-wrapper'>
    <div class='chat-microphone-container'>
      <div class='chat-microphone'></div>
    </div>
    <div class='inputbox-container'>
      <div class='inputbox-wrapper'>
        <textarea type='text' class='chat-input-box'></textarea>
        <div class='input-box-btn'></div>
      </div>
      <div class='input-character-container'>
        <span class='input-character'>

          250 out of 250 characters left
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.chat-inputbox-container {
  /* border: 1px solid red; */
  width: 100%;
  height: 113px;
  align-self: flex-end;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.chat-inputbox-wrapper {
  width: 736px;
  height: 92px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.chat-microphone-container {
  width: 32px;

  height: 92px;
  /* border: 1px solid orange; */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.chat-microphone {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;

  background: orangered;
}

.inputbox-wrapper {
  width: 694px;
  height: 52px;
  /* border: 1px solid blue; */
  display: flex;
  align-self: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 16px;

  background: gray;

  border: 1px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.chat-input-box {
  width: 632px;
  height: 20px;

  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 20px;

  border: hidden;
  background: #f7f7f7;
  outline: none;
  color: #0d1c3d;
  margin: 16px 10px;
}

.input-box-btn {
  /* Auto Layout */

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0px;

  position: static;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;

  margin-right: 10px;
  background: #0078b3;
  border-radius: 4px;
  flex: none;
  order: 0;
  flex-grow: 0;
  margin: 0px 0px;
}

.input-character-container {
}

.input-character {
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 16px;
  color: #677083;
}
```

Comment: Do yo mean that you want the bottom of the text box to stay in one place on the viewport so it appears that it (and its parent) are expanding upwards e.g. that a scroll of one line's worth height takes place on a newline or as the text wraps?

Answer (score 3):

We can use a Javascript ResizeObserver to tell us when the height of the input text has changed. Then we can scroll the window in such a way that the bottom of the input stays in the same position on the viewport - so the elements seem to grow upwards.

Note this snippet uses contenteditable on a div rather than a textarea as the growing/shrinking and text wrapping then happen automatically.

```html
<style>
  body {
    height: 300vh;
  }
  
  .parent {
    margin-top: 20vh; /* so we can see it growing not just disappearing */
    background: pink;
  }
  
  .child {
    background: #eeeeee;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <div class="parent">
    Some stuff in the parent<br> here
    <div class="child" contenteditable></div>
  </div>
  <script>
    let prevH = 0;
    const textArea = document.querySelector('.child');
    const resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver(entries => {
      for (let entry of entries) {
        let h = entry.contentRect.height;
        let diff = h - prevH;
        if (diff != 0) {
          prevH = h;
          window.scroll(0, prevH);
        }
      }
    });
    resizeObserver.observe(textArea);
  </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't hard code the `height` of class `.inputbox-wrapper` instead remove height property from there or put `height: auto`(which is default value) so that container expand when the the `text-area` is expanded

```css
.chat-inputbox-container {
  /* border: 1px solid red; */
  width: 100%;
  height: 113px;
  align-self: flex-end;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.chat-inputbox-wrapper {
  width: 736px;
  height: 92px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.chat-microphone-container {
  width: 32px;

  height: 92px;
  /* border: 1px solid orange; */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.chat-microphone {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;

  background: orangered;
}

.inputbox-wrapper {
  width: 694px;
  height: auto;/*Change here*/
  /* border: 1px solid blue; */
  display: flex;
  align-self: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 16px;

  background: gray;

  border: 1px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.chat-input-box {
  width: 632px;
  height: 20px;

  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 20px;

  border: hidden;
  background: #f7f7f7;
  outline: none;
  color: #0d1c3d;
  margin: 16px 10px;
}

.input-box-btn {
  /* Auto Layout */

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0px;

  position: static;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;

  margin-right: 10px;
  background: #0078b3;
  border-radius: 4px;
  flex: none;
  order: 0;
  flex-grow: 0;
  margin: 0px 0px;
}

.input-character-container {
}

.input-character {
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 16px;
  color: #677083;
}
```

```html
<div class='chat-inputbox-container'>
  <div class='chat-inputbox-wrapper'>
    <div class='chat-microphone-container'>
      <div class='chat-microphone'></div>
    </div>
    <div class='inputbox-container'>
      <div class='inputbox-wrapper'>
        <textarea type='text' class='chat-input-box'></textarea>
        <div class='input-box-btn'></div>
      </div>
      <div class='input-character-container'>
        <span class='input-character'>

          250 out of 250 characters left
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `.inputbox-wrapper` should have a `min-height` not a `height` if you set only a **height**, the container will not resize with the `textbox`.

On another note, if you want the textarea to expand vertically only, you can add `resize: vertical;` to `.chat-input-box {`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Textboxes can't expand their height automatically like this by default - you'll need to use a bit of Javascript.

One approach is to dynamically calculate the height of the textfield based on the number of line breaks inside it.

[This example](https://css-tricks.com/auto-growing-inputs-textareas/) from CSS-Tricks has more details on the approach. I've implemented it on your code below.

You also need to change `height` to `min-height` on your `inputbox-wrapper` to allow it to expand as the textfield changes height.

```js
let textarea = document.querySelector(".chat-input-box");
textarea.addEventListener("keyup", () => {
  textarea.style.height = calcHeight(textarea.value) + "px";
});

function calcHeight(value) {
  let numberOfLineBreaks = (value.match(/\n/g) || []).length;
  // min-height + lines x line-height + padding + border
  let newHeight = 20 + numberOfLineBreaks * 20 + 0 + 0;
  // padding and border are both 0 here but have left in for reference
  return newHeight;
}
```

```css
.chat-inputbox-container {
  /* border: 1px solid red; */
  width: 100%;
  height: 113px;
  align-self: flex-end;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.chat-inputbox-wrapper {
  width: 736px;
  height: 92px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.chat-microphone-container {
  width: 32px;

  height: 92px;
  /* border: 1px solid orange; */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.chat-microphone {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;

  background: orangered;
}

.inputbox-wrapper {
  width: 694px;
  min-height: 52px;
  /* border: 1px solid blue; */
  display: flex;
  align-self: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 16px;

  background: gray;

  border: 1px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.chat-input-box {
  width: 632px;
  height: 20px;

  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 20px;

  border: hidden;
  background: #f7f7f7;
  outline: none;
  color: #0d1c3d;
  margin: 16px 10px;
}

.input-box-btn {
  /* Auto Layout */

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0px;

  position: static;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;

  margin-right: 10px;
  background: #0078b3;
  border-radius: 4px;
  flex: none;
  order: 0;
  flex-grow: 0;
  margin: 0px 0px;
}

.input-character-container {
}

.input-character {
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 16px;
  color: #677083;
}
```

```html
<div class='chat-inputbox-container'>
  <div class='chat-inputbox-wrapper'>
    <div class='chat-microphone-container'>
      <div class='chat-microphone'></div>
    </div>
    <div class='inputbox-container'>
      <div class='inputbox-wrapper'>
        <textarea type='text' class='chat-input-box'></textarea>
        <div class='input-box-btn'></div>
      </div>
      <div class='input-character-container'>
        <span class='input-character'>

          250 out of 250 characters left
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @dave, Thank you for the quick response. How can we make the textarea expand upwards instead of downwards?